# Blackberry with Eclipse - How can I get rid of multiple Debug Servers?

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

Each time I choose 'run' it creates a DebugServer (in the debug view).  Almost all the context menu options are disabled, including 'Terminate' option.

Is there a way to get rid of these without restarting Eclipse (every dozen runs or so)?

Thanks,

Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, after you will Terminate or Disconnect debug session, it will be marked as

<
terminated> 
DebugServer [BlackBerry Simulator]

<
disconnected>RIM JVM

and you can remove it with context menu Remove All Terminated

Otherwise something may be wrong with system (conflict with system defence software, wrong BB eJDE setup, insufficient memory/CPU resources etc)

However you can always terminate debug server by killing fledge.exe and BbDevMgr.exe